# pip not working while trying to install torch

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install torch for ml-agents and when I run the command

`pip install torch~=1.7.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

and it answers:

`No Python at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe'`

Comment: Try `python -m pip ...`

Comment: Install python, and don't forget to add Python to the Environment Path

Answer (score 0):

review/reinstall your python installation. The issue is related to Python and Pip, not that library.
First try to fix:

```
python --version
```

then

```
pip --version
```